# Need help matching descriptions in Kubernetes YAML file

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I am reading Core Kubernetes by Vyas and Love.  This is from page 141, section 7.3.  It seems that the annotations and the location indicated by the arrows don't match. I have redone the matching using the numbers and brackets.  Could someone tell me if I have done anything wrong?  TIA!

[image: img]

Comment: some are wrong, can you provide the image or yaml so i can draw it?

Comment: i was wrong, nothing wrong in the images. except number 4 should not include shared emptyDir volume.

Comment: As the above comment emptyDir should not be included; moreover could you please share the source of the page where we can look more briefly ?